# microk8s Default Username and Password?

Tags: password, default, username, microk8s

I have installed microk8s on my Windows 10 machine using Hyper-V.  I would like to SSH into the microk8s-vm using Putty.  What is the default username and password to do this?

Comment: How is this a Ubuntu question?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230753/login-and-password-for-multipass-instance