# After doing multipass upgrade I cannot list my previous VM

Tags: upgrade, password, multipass

After some Windows 10 patches were applied two day ago I had issues to connect to the VM running on Multipass, so I did an upgrade to "multipass  1.6.2+win" and after that I could not list the previous VM.

I can see the VM through Hyper-V, but I cannot access because I don´t know which is the default password

VM seen on Hyper-V but I cannot access

[image]

Some guideline that someone can provide I´ll appreciate

Thanks
Hugo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login and password for multipass instance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230753/login-and-password-for-multipass-instance)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have reinstalled "multipass  1.5.0+win" and copied the directory "C:\Windows.old\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\multipassd" to the new Windows directory. All this began with the upgrade to "Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2 19042.928", now I can see the vm, but the message received after "multipass start" is "timed out waiting for response". I have tried  on PowerShell "Get-HNSNetwork | ? Name -Like "Default Switch" | Remove-HNSNetwork", restart the laptop but the issue continues. Any guideline?

Comment: That is an entirely different question and requires troubleshooting. Comments are not for extended discussion because this isn't a forum.